# What happen when use rs232 instead of usb in arduino?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication, serial-communication

I just start a project which is very basic actually. But I need an information. It is about arduino serial communication. Here is the question.

If I connect arduino to computer using TTL to RS232 converter without USB cable then can I still use serial monitor to get some data or what happens ? Assume arduino is programmed before using usb cable, and it is powered externally when usb is not used.

for instance the code just

```
Serial.println("It is working");
delay(1000);
```

Thansk a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you will fry it. Standard RS232 use a +-12V level, while arduino use TTL level (0-5V), so you still need a RS232 -> RS232TTL converter. If you use it, then using virtual serial over USB or real hardware serial is exactly the same, except that hardware serial port never appear/disappear when you plug in the arduino (there is not something like plug'n'play in rs232, it is always plugged)

Comment: Hey thanks so much I will keep to ask a question from here !!

Comment: You mean, it is just needed http://www.ebay.com/itm/RS232-Serial-Port-to-TTL-Converter-Communication-Module-for-Arduino-/360706675866?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item53fbcb149a to do what ı want exaclt without any harm to electronical components.

Comment: Exactly, you can even use some diode but it is a bad hack :)

Comment: diode ? Can you give me any link about that ?

Comment: sorry, the (5v zener) diode works only one way (pc to arduino), but you can use a coupleof transistor and resistence http://www.botkin.org/dale/rs232_interface.htm

Comment: My friend !! 
I tried ttl - rs 232 converter and end of the rs232 cable ı connect rs232 to usb converter. Then using usb I connect the computer with arduino. But arduino could not sent any data.

Comment: Pay attention, are u sure it is a usb/rs232 not already ttl? Because those are quite common

Comment: I realize that, When ı use Serial.println("hi") first the data is going through usb cable not rx tx pins. Why this happen ?

Comment: RX and TX pin of the arduino ARE connected with the on board USB to RS232ttl, they are used for coomunication AND programmation. Use other pin with SoftSerial to test. BTW if connection are correct, you should "sniff" it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561910/rs232-arduino-issue look what ı have now