# Rs232 arduino issue

Tags: serial-port, arduino, serial-communication, ttl

I have a little confusing about arduino uno. I use Serial.print("hi") code then it "hi" appears on the serial monitor. I also use rs232/ttl converter which are connected pin 1 and 0 on the arduino properly. 
Then I realize that when serial.print("hi") working the data first is going through usb cable. But I want the data has to go through tx rx pins which are 1 and 0.
 But when I enter some data from serial monitor , rs232/ttl will work and  some data will be sended ? 
I do not understand the situation?

Why this is happening ? I just want to sent a data from pin 1 and 0 using rs232/ttl converter.
How can I do that ? I do not use usb cable to sent datas.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the data coming from and to your PC by default USB port, then you ARE using pin 0 and 1.
If you correctly connect an extenal converster, you should be able to read exactly the same thing, if not, connection are wrong. Classic error is to switch TX and RX, as they have to be crossed.

Also remeber that RS232 does not support multiple host, but normally give no problem if the "others host" are just reading, as they will simply sniff the connection.

Comment: But still information goes to usb serial not to pin 1 and 0. I want just when say "hi" on the serial monitor it will also appear on the rx tx pins. But it does not happen. Arduino sents data only from usb cable.

Comment: Using Serial mean use of pin 0 and 1. Then those pin are connected with an onboard connector with goes to USB. if you don't trust me, just go and look at the arduino schematics, they are open-source!

If you don't see that data over pin 0 and 1, it means that your probe is not correctly connected, os is using a wrong connection. What are your connection? did you try to cross TX and RX?